# How to test Azure Function Scalability?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app

As we're new to the Azure Function App where we heard one of its great functionality was **scalability**, but how did azure function scale works out? Was it automatically scaling in behind or any mechanism we can set up? For example, max of scale size limitation.

When we debug the azure function locally (we've tried *ServiceBusTrigger, EventHubTrigger, QueueTrigger and CosmosDBTrigger*), it seems like **every time the same function instance was called multiple times over and over** while we continue sending messages, which doesn't work as scaling/working parallel as we expected, is there any good way of debugging the scalability locally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scaling of Azure Functions is determined by the [Scale Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#runtime-scaling):

[image: Scale controller]

The Scale Controller only runs in the cloud so it is not possible to test the scaling locally. Also the inner workings of this controller are not disclosed.

The best way to test the scaling is to actually do a proof of concept in the cloud and make sure you [configure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring). Once you have load tested your function app you can do a Log Analytics query such as the following one to see if multiple instances of your function app have been provisioned:

```
requests | 
project timestamp, id, operation_Id, operation_Name, duration, cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance | 
where cloud_RoleName =~ 'FUNCTION_APP_NAME' | 
order by timestamp desc | 
take 100
```

The cloud_RoleInstance property has the ID of the resource that has been provisioned. When that column contains muliple values you know that scaling has occurred.

[image: Log Analytics]

To be honest, testing if Azure Functions autoscales should not be a primary concern to you since it's the responsibility of Azure. You probaly need the autoscaling to handle both small and large workloads and you might have time constraints in which the processing should be finished. If that is your real concern then you might be better off measuring the end-to-end performance/timings.

Comment: I would love to know if you could force the local emulator to run many instances. Not for debugging, but to sniff out concurrency issues.

Answer (score 4):

The scalability of azure function depends on the [hosting plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#hosting-plan-support), and there're 3 types of hosting plan: Consumption plan, Premium plan(it's in preview, so we can ignore it now), Dedicated plan(app service plan).

For [Consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan), it scales automatically based on the number of incoming events.

For [app service plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan), you can manually scale out by adding more VM instances, or you can also enable autoscale. More details you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/autoscale-get-started?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Ftoc.json).

And when you run it locally without hosting plan, you cannot see this behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not seeing how the scaling would work when debugging locally in visual studio is a big drawback. I get that your local development machine won't match the hardware in Azure but some kind of middle ground to show the scaling would be nice.